# setAttribute to var string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add to each of the following var a Link string and into my HTML the only thing I have is a simple div with a ID set.

```js
var home = "Home";
var news = "News";
var contact = "Contact";
var about = "About";
document.getElementById("myTopnav").innerHTML = home + " " + news + " " + contact + " " + about;
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

</div>
```

As you can see it is a Menu and I want to create only one using JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Link string and into my HTML"? A link tag?

Comment: I want each of the var to have a link to a page just like a menu

Comment: The link you posted doesn't seem to attend him @msanford. He wants to do this in vanilla js, not jQuery

Comment: I want to do this pure javascript not jquery

Comment: Even better! [Create an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and then [append it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: can you show a example?

Comment: Your post title "setAttribute to var string in Javascript" is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are just getting started, so I suggest starting off in a maintainable way. Define your menu items in a list, not individual variables, and then step through and append an `a` tag. Like this:

```js
var menuItems = [{
        name:"Home",
        link:"/home"
    },
    {
        name:"News",
        link:"/news"
    },
    {
        name:"Contact",
        link:"/contact"
    },
    {
        name:"About",
        link:"/about"
    }]
var menu = document.getElementById("myTopnav")
for(var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(menuItems[i].name);
    link.appendChild(linkText);
    link.href = menuItems[i].link;
    menu.appendChild(link);
}
```

```css
#myTopnav a{
        margin-left: 10px
    }
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>
```

Comment: This is so awesome. And you are right I just started :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"></div>

<script>
var links = [
  ['Home', '/'],
  ['News', '/news/'],
  ['Contact', '/contact/'],
  ['About', '/about/']
];

function makeNav( links ) {
  var nav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    nav.innerHTML += '<a href="' + links[i][1] + '">' + links[i][0] + '</a>';
  }
  return nav;
}

makeNav( links );
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want it as a list. I want it normal on 1 strate bar

Comment: ok. edited now to flat list

Comment: great work nice

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your elements in html tags like `<a></a> or <li><a></a></li>`.

```
document.getElementById('myTopnav').innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + home + '</a>' + ...
```